# PIC16F15257 ISSUE with different output pin voltages

Tags: c, pic, mplab

Anyone have an idea as to why a pic will have very different output voltages on certain pins ??
I use multiple outputs on one switch and sometimes the one pin will show 4 to 5 volts output in one switched circuit and below 1 volt in another swithced circuit and 2-3 in another, etc !
the IO's in use sometimes share a register, but sometimes do not.

Tried switching from analog to digital outputs, same problem.

I setup a test setup using one switch and 12 outputs ,8 to a single led and 4 to 2 ,2 channel cmos compatible high-side power transistors, at one time and that MOSTLY worked, so I do not think that it is a power issue. 3 pins showed low voltage but two of those are two that I just added into the mix.
Tried two different pics that were new and the same number, and both do it.
Any  thoughts ??
On the code I just added (only a small segment of what I had done), RIGHT has the most issues.
JUST DID A DC VOLTAGE TEST; when RIGHT is on: RD2 has 4.8v -RD3 has .98.. When all are on. They all show around 4.8 except RD2 shows 2.9 -RD3 shows 1.64 and RB3 shows1.45,and up shows 4.8 on RD2 and 2.4 on RD3. So one pin (RD3) is actually lower with less outputs on ??

```
#include "mcc_generated_files/mcc.h"

/*
                         Main application
 */
void main(void)
{
    // initialize the device
    SYSTEM_Initialize();

         while ( RA3 == 0 ) /*POWER LED OFF*/     
    {/*B*/ 
               /*SWITCH TURNS ON RA3 pwr LITE AND RA7 backlite PLUS OTHER FUNCTIONS BELOW IT*/    
        /*tap on POWER */  if (RE1 == 0) RA3 = 1, RA7 = 1;
 
          while  (RA7 == 1) /*POWER LED SENSED AS ON and ALLOWS FUNCTIONS IN BRACKETS "C" TO WORK*/
            {/*C*/ /*all standard functions */    
        /*OFF */{ if (RD5 == 0)  RA3 = 0,RA7 = 0, RA0 = 0, RA1 = 0 , RA5 = 0, RA6 = 0, RC1 = 0, RD2 = 0, RD3 = 0, RC7 = 0, RB4 = 0, RD7 = 0;}
        /*TURNS OFF OTHER FUNCTIONS BELOW IF THEY ARE ON
        
        /* (UP) (MOMENTARY) RD7 COIL 5 & RB1 COIL 7*/ 
                { if (RD0 == 0) RD3 = 1 , RD7 = 1, RA5 = 0, RA0 = 0;  else  RD3 = 0, RD7 = 0 ;}               
        /*(DOWN)(LOCKING) RA0 FLOAT LIGHT & RA0 & COIL 6 RA5*/
                { if (RC2 == 0) RA5 = 1 , RA0 = 1 ;} 
        /*RIGHT  RC0 to  4 RBO + 7 RB1*/
                { if (RB3 == 0) RD2 = 1 , RD3 = 1;  else  RD2 = 0, RD3 = 0;}
                
        /* LEFT  RD1 IS SWITCH TO (2OUT RC7 + 7OUT RB1)*/ 
                { if(RD1 == 0)  RC7 = 1 , RD3 = 1;  else  RC7 = 0, RD3= 0 ;} 
                { if (RA4 == 0) RA0 = 1, RA1 = 1 , RA5 = 1, RA6 = 1, RC1 = 1, RD2 = 1, RD3 = 1, RC7 = 1, RB4 = 1, RD7 = 1;}
            /*C*/      /*on this test line - RB1, RD2 AND RD3 ARE THE WEAK OUTPUTS*/
          }         /*THESE 3 AND RB0 ALSO WILL NOT LOCK LIKE THE REST DO ON IN THIS STATEMENT*/
  
    }/*B*/

}/*A*/
```

Comment: It is doing that on a C code that I wrote, but I have no clue if the code is the issue ? The code is a very basic one. I do not know how to post the code after the question has already been posted. I asked someone else before and I received no answer.

Comment: Not familiar with the `pic15f15257` specifically, but generally microcontroller pin voltage values tend to "float". That is why they are most often used in a "pull-up" or "pull-down* configuration. See: [Pull-up Resistor and Pull-down Resistor Explained](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/logic/pull-up-resistor.html) Other ADC configurations measure the pin voltages directly, but though a specifically configured range of values. PWM (for e.g. motor controllers) set pin-voltage as a percentage of time the pin is powered or off (the pulse-width) It's not apparent from your code which is used.

Comment: I guess the problem is here: `SYSTEM_Initialize();`.  And remember: Output only to `LATx`and input prom `PORTx`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the schematic.

Comment: I did not make up a schematic.    All switches are set as inputs and to high and have a 10k resistor to 5v. Outputs are set to output and to low and digital and go to an led then to a 200 ohm resistor to ground. IOs were all set using MCC.

Comment: UPDATE; After hours of building a completely new board with all different inputs and outputs and a new program, I still have the same type issue. It looks like the program is not allowing me to share outputs with another switch function and it is choosing priority over which of the shared pins to use with which switch willy nilly.. ANY thoughts ? Thanks again, Fran

Comment: Please do shematic! You can use  "https://easyeda.com/editor" it is free.